# removing the repeated words using haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i want to remove the repeated words in the string..

```
eg: if input is "he is the the good boy boy"
       out put is "he is the good boy"
```

i done the coding but it is not working properly.

```
deleterepeat:: String -> String
deleterepeat []  = []
deleterepeat [xs] = [xs]
deleterepeat (xs1:xs2:xs)
      | xs1 == xs2  = deleterepeat (xs1:xs)
      | otherwise = xs1 : deleterepeat (xs2:xs)

removeall :: String -> String
removeall = unwords . map deleterepeat. words
```

this works with characters.. but not with words..

can some one help me to fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `deleterepeat` is working on a `String`, i.e. a `[Char]`, rather than `[String]`. This means that it's removing repeated characters in each word, rather than repeated words.

Either change the type to `Eq a => [a] -> [a]` or to `[String] -> [String]`, and also call it directly on the entire list of words, i.e. use `deleterepeat` rather than `map deleterepeat`.

Comment: no still didnt work properly.. but it works like this..

**FirstScript> deleterepeat ["hi this is is sathy"]**
result  **["hi this is is sathy"]**
**FirstScript> deleterepeat ["hi this is is sathy", "hi this is is sathy"]**
result **["hi this is is sathy"]**

Comment: `deleterepeat` will delete repeats from the "top-level" of the list it is passed, so what you're seeing with that input is as expected. If you change your program in the question as I described then the input to `deleterepeat` will be a list of separate words, and `removeall "hi this is is sathy"` will call `deleterepeat ["hi", "this", "is", "is", "sathy"]`, eventually producing `"hi this is sathy"` as expected.

Comment: ya.. that works..but is there anyway, i can get the string and split it in to words.. so that i can send it in to this function?

Comment: You're already doing that with `words` in your original code in the question - am I missing something?

Comment: ya. thank you. but when i try to do this that give me an error

`deleteall :: [String] -> [String]
deleteall = unwords . map deleterepeat. words`

Comment: Your original question has `removeall :: String -> String` not `deleteall :: [String] -> [String]`. The first type signature is correct for the top-level function that starts with a single string and returns another string, breaking it up into words as an intermediate step before calling `deleterepeat`. You still need to remove the `map` from the `deleterepeat` call of course.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of deleterepeat to [String]->[String], and remove the map.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been much easier simply to use the functions "words" and "nub" from Data.List.

Comment: `nub` removes all duplicates rather than just adjacent duplicates.